# Question on Hessian of a function (probability question)

Tags: pr.probability

Let $f(x): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued twice continuously differentiable function and $n>1$. I define the function $g(x) = f(x) + x^{\top} A x$ where $A$ is random matrix (say entries i.i.d from uniform distribution [-1,1]).
Can we say that the Hessian of $g$ is invertible for all $x$ with probability one?

Comment: The Hessian of $f'$, I guess you mean?  (Can we call it something that looks less like a derivative?)

Comment: Fixed, thank you!

Comment: If $f$ is three times continuously differentiable, then the Hessian $Hf$ is a $C^1$ map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, so its image has Hausdorff dimension $n$ and hence Lebesgue measure zero.  In particular $Hg$ is everywhere nonzero with probability one, which is a start.  But if $Hf$ is merely continuous then it seems like we could get some bad behavior.

Comment: Nice start Nate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my counterexample:
Take $f(x)=\|x\|^4$, then for any $x\neq 0$, by spherical symetry, $x$ is a eigenvector of $Hf|_x$. we have then 
$$Hf|_x(x)=a\|x\|^2 x $$
We can choose $x=v$ an eigenvector on $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$. ie $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)(v)=\lambda v$ then with $t\in \mathbb{R}$
$$ (Hg)|_{tv}=(Hf+A)|_{tv}(v)=(a\|v\|^2 t^2 +\lambda) v $$
Therefore for $t^2=-\lambda/(a\|v \|^2)$. $Hg|_{tv}(v)=0$ and it is then not invertible.

For a more general counterexample, take $f$ such that there exist $x_1,x_2$ with $det(Hf(x_1))<0$ and $det(Hf(x_2))>0$, then for comparatively small random matrix $A$, $det(Hf(x_2)+A)>0$ and $det(Hf(x_1)+A)<0$ and by continuity. There exist $x_0$ such that $Hg(x_0)$ is not invertible.

Comment: Hi, what I don't understand is that you assume $\lambda, \alpha$ have opposite signs with positive probability? $t$ is a real so $\frac{-\lambda}{\alpha ||v||^2}>0$.

Comment: What is $a$?   (this comment was otherwise too short)

Comment: (a=4*3=12.)  Yes, with positive probabily there exists $\lambda<0$, this particular example don't work otherwise. Insteed of $\|x\|^4$, one could have also taken $f(x)=F(\| x \|)$, with  $F$ has a surjective seconde derivative.

Answer (score 1):

It's false for $n = 1,$ since then if $f$ is the double integral of your favorite surjective function $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},$ then the answer is NO.

Comment: Nice example! This is not what I am looking for because it is a trivial case (when $n=1$), it is also true that $n^2 = n$ for the case $ n=1$.

Comment: Can we even show it for a neighborhood around a critical point of $f$? Because some union bound argument should work afterwards. Any ideas?