# Lifting a determinant map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, riemannian-geometry

This is a kind of a follow-up to [Question on Hessian of a function (probability question)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292607/question-on-hessian-of-a-function-probability-question). Suppose I give you a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}.$ Is it true that there exists a ($C^2$) function $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},$ such that $\det(\mbox{Hess}(g)) = f?$ (where $\mbox{Hess}$ is the Hessian, of course)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%E2%80%93Amp%C3%A8re_equation

Comment: @WillJagy Truly you are wise in the ways of science! However, the question is somewhat less general than the general Monge-Ampere equation, in that $f$ only depends on $x$ in my question, and not on $u, u^\prime,$ so that should be easier, I should think...

Comment: If you don’t restrict $f$ to be a positive function, then very little is known. If $f > 0$, you can try to solve for a convex solution  Then the PDE is elliptic, so there is hope. I’m not sure what is known for a Monge-Ampère equation on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But your colleague Cristian Gutierrez is an expert on this.

Comment: @DeaneYang I read Cristian's book (ok, skimmed) yesterday, and, as you say, it's all about positive $f,$ and even then I cannot figure out if you can ever get $C^2$ regularity. The case of interest for the referenced question is the sign-variable question, about which nothing is known, and I can't even find too much on the hyperbolic Monge-Ampere (and Cristian does not mention it).

Comment: For the positive $f$ case, elliptic theory gives only Holder estimates and never exactly $C^2$. So the best you can hope for is that if $k \ge 0$, $0 < \alpha < 1$, and $f$ is $C^{k,\alpha}$, then $g$ is $C^{k+2,\alpha}$. I say "hope for", because I don't know what exactly is known.

Comment: If $f$ is negative or has mixed sign, then there are results only for existence of a solution near a given point, i.e., local solutions. If $\nabla f \ne 0$, then it's known as a Tricomi-type equation, which was studied notably by Cathleen Morawetz. If $f < 0$, then you can solve for local solutions by assuming that the Hessian of $g$ has one negative eigenvalue and the rest positive and using the theory of nonlinear hyperbolic PDEs. Currently, there is absolutely no hope of finding global solutions when $f$ is not strictly positive. A radically new idea is needed.

Comment: Igor, years ago I was asking at Cody's bookstore for a periodical on soccer from England. The person helping me said "Let me find you someone wise in the ways of magazines"