# Integrating matrix maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integrable-systems

This (which is a follow-up to [Lifting a determinant map](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292690/lifting-a-determinant-map?noredirect=1#comment726277_292690)) must be standard, and yet I am failing to find a reference. Consider a map $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to M^{n\times n}.$ You can pick its degree of regularity to maximize your happiness, but the question is whether (and how) you can find a map $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that its Hessian is given by $f.$ Now, if one does it in steps: first find a function $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ of which $f$ is the Jacobian, and then find $f$ of which $h$ is the gradient, you get a debauche of integrability conditions, which seems hard to make sense of, but there must be a nice way to express it.

A related (and, I am guessing, easier) question is as above with $\mathbb{R}^n$ replaced by $\mathbb{C}P^n,$ matrices now being complex (if, instead of matrices, you would prefer your favorite algebraic group, that is of interest too), and the map should be a rational map.

Comment: But you don’t get a debauche of integrability conditions. If you write down all of the equations that $g$ and $h$ need to satisfy, the only integrability condition needed is that third partials commute. The proof is essentially the same as for the Poincaré Lemma.

Comment: @DeaneYang third partials of the mysterious $g?$ So, what does this translate to for the data ($f$)? That $\frac{\partial f_{ij}}{x_k} = \frac{\partial f_{ik}}{x_j}?,$ plus the symmetry of the matrix?  (the latter needed to go from $h$ to $g$). This is somehow unsatisfying, because it is not very geometric to me - if I have a disk sitting in $S^{n\times n}$ (symmetric matrices), how do I tell a disk which comes from such a construction from one which does not?!

Comment: the map $f$ matters, not just its image.

Comment: @DeaneYang Yes, of course. Does it mean that every image can be reparametrized?

Comment: good question. I don’t know

Answer (score 4):

This is essentially the Poincaré lemma. You can write it as a first order system of equations:
$$ \partial_ig = p_i $$
$$ \partial_jp_i = f_{ij} $$
The obvious necessary conditions are:
$$ \partial_if_{jk} = \partial_jf_{ik} $$
They can be shown to be sufficient by integrating the equations one coordinate at a time as follows:

Assume that the equations above hold for $1 \le i,j,k \le n-1$ along the hyperplane $x^n = 0$. You can extend $g, p_i$ to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by integrating the equations
$$ \partial_n g = p_n $$
$$ \partial_n p_i = f_{ni},\ 1 \le i \le n $$
You then check that the equations for $1 \le i,j,k \le n-1$ must also continue to hold on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, because they hold, by inductive assumption, on $x^n = 0$ and, by the equations above,
$$ \partial_n(\partial_ig - p_i) = \partial_i(\partial_nu - p_n) = 0 $$
$$ \partial_n(\partial_jp_i - f_{ij}) = \partial_j(\partial_np_i - f_{ni}) = 0 $$